# how can use a loop to draw it multiple times in random places in my canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, canvas, html5-canvas

I've drawn a leaf in canvas, but now i want to draw it multiple times on my canvas and in random places. I've mostly used bezier curves to draw my leaf, is and i do not know how to use a loop to create more of them in random places, because of the coordinates.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="800" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">

</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = c.getContext("2d");

       context.lineWidth = 5;


      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(100, 150);

      context.strokeStyle="#009900";
      context.bezierCurveTo(170, 110, 400, 10, 500, 150);
      context.stroke();



      context.moveTo(100, 150);
      context.strokeStyle="#009900";
      context.bezierCurveTo(170, 130, 430, 310, 500, 150);
      context.stroke();
      context.fillStyle = '#99FF66';
      context.fill();


      context.strokeStyle="#009900";
      context.moveTo(250, 150);
      context.bezierCurveTo(400, 100, 400, 180, 500, 150);
      context.stroke();
       context.closePath();


      context.beginPath();
      context.strokeStyle="#996633";
      context.moveTo(500, 150);
      context.lineTo(580,150);
      context.stroke();
      context.closePath();





</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Randomly generate an X and Y value which will be the starting point and add that to all of your initial values.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution that I can come up with is to use the [context.translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate) function to move to where you want to draw the leaf before drawing it:

```
        //Generate x y coords, offset by the x,y of the leaf:
        var x = (Math.random()*500) - 250;
        var y = (Math.random()*500) - 150;
        //Translate
        context.translate(x, y);
        //Draw leaf
        //Translate back
        context.translate(-x,-y)
```

Code to draw two leaves at random positions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="800" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">

</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = c.getContext("2d");

      context.lineWidth = 5;
      for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            //Generate x y coords, offset by the top x,y of the leaf:
            var x = (Math.random()*500) - 250;
            var y = (Math.random()*500) - 150;
            //Translate
            context.translate(x, y);

            //Draw
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(100, 150);

            context.strokeStyle="#009900";
            context.bezierCurveTo(170, 110, 400, 10, 500, 150);
            context.stroke();



            context.moveTo(100, 150);
            context.strokeStyle="#009900";
            context.bezierCurveTo(170, 130, 430, 310, 500, 150);
            context.stroke();
            context.fillStyle = '#99FF66';
            context.fill();


            context.strokeStyle="#009900";
            context.moveTo(250, 150);
            context.bezierCurveTo(400, 100, 400, 180, 500, 150);
            context.stroke();
            context.closePath();


            context.beginPath();
            context.strokeStyle="#996633";
            context.moveTo(500, 150);
            context.lineTo(580,150);
            context.stroke();
            context.closePath();

            //Translate Back
            context.translate(-x, -y);
      }


</script>

</body>
```

Comment: you might want to change the offsets slightly (they're a little close together)

Comment: Is there any way to create more than two?

Comment: Create as many as you need by increasing the "2" in `for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) `

Comment: @OliverBarnwell, After you do `context.translate(x,y)` and finish your drawing, you'll want to reset the canvas by doing `context.translate(-x,-y)` just before the end of each loop. Otherwise your drawings will quickly become translated off the canvas. ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Will make the necessary amendments :)

Comment: When i create another random number can i use this with context.rotation too?

Comment: Yes, to rotate you provide the angle you want to rotate the canvas by in radians, so you multiply your random number by (PI/180). Example: context.rotate((Math.random()*360)*(PI/180))

Answer (score -1):

Since you want to re-use some of your code -> isolate the parameters and build a function out of it.
Then any pattern will be easy to build.

http://jsbin.com/mimisuziyi/1/

```
function drawLeaf(x,y, size, rotation) {
       context.lineWidth = 5;

      context.save();
      context.translate(x,y);
      context.scale(size/400, size/400);
      context.rotate(rotation);
      context.beginPath();

      context.moveTo(0, 0);

      context.strokeStyle="#009900";
      context.bezierCurveTo(70, -40, 300, 10-150, 400, 0);
      context.stroke();

      context.moveTo(0, 0);
      context.strokeStyle="#009900";
      context.bezierCurveTo(70, -20, 330, 160, 400, 0);
      context.stroke();
      context.fillStyle = '#99FF66';
      context.fill();


      context.strokeStyle="#009900";
      context.moveTo(150, 0);
      context.bezierCurveTo(300, -50, 300, 30, 400, 0);
      context.stroke();
       context.closePath();


      context.beginPath();
      context.strokeStyle="#996633";
      context.moveTo(400, 0);
      context.lineTo(480,0);
      context.closePath();
      context.stroke();

      context.restore();
}
```

used with :

```
 drawLeaf(100, 150, 400, 0);
```

or :

```
var leafCount = 5;
for (var i=0; i<leafCount; i++) {
  drawLeaf(150, 300, 100, 2*i*Math.PI/leafCount)
}
```